# nvm use exit status 1: Access is denied

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, nvm, nvm-windows

I had installed nodejs before without nvm and then deleted it completely by uninstalling and deleting all files.

I am using windows 10.

It works when I use run powershell as administrator, but I am unable to use yarn in vscode.

```
PS C:\Users\laveen> nvm ls

No installations recognized.
PS C:\Users\laveen> nvm install 14.18.1
Downloading node.js version 14.18.1 (64-bit)...
Complete
Creating C:\Users\laveen\AppData\Roaming\nvm\temp

Downloading npm version 6.14.15... Complete
Installing npm v6.14.15...

Installation complete. If you want to use this version, type

nvm use 14.18.1
PS C:\Users\laveen> nvm use 14.18.1
exit status 1: Access is denied.
```

Answer (score 14):

run command prompt as administrator.

Answer (score 10):

1.Run the same command as administrator command window like shown in image

2.nvm use 14.8.1

[image]

Comment: Please wrap the commands in this post in code-snippets.

Answer (score 1):

First check node is properly install in your system

1. Open CMD/Git CMD as administrator (Press Windows+R Type “cmd” and then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter)
2. Check list of Node version ( nvm list )
3. Use specific node version ( nvm use 17.7.1 )

[image]

Comment: This answer was very helpful for me. I didn't know how to open cmd as administrator, but you tought me. I recommend this answer to solve this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My case with nvm-windows version 1.1.9: Switching node version requires elevated Powershell (run as administrator). It is recommended to use version 1.1.7 to avoid this issue.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is you have run command prompt as administrator, then it will work [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkN0I.png)